# Process selection rather than entire folder

Tags: vba, outlook

In reference to the below code, what I am looking to do is rather than process an entire folder I would like only to process the emails that I selected.
Otherwise it works perfectly.

Jeff

Requires the following references:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation

  ```
  Public Sub SaveOLFolderAttachments()

       ' Ask the user to select a file system folder for saving the attachments
       Dim oShell As Object
       Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
       Dim fsSaveFolder As Object
       Set fsSaveFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please Select a Save Folder:", 1)
       If fsSaveFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       ' Note:  BrowseForFolder doesn't add a trailing slash

       ' Ask the user to select an Outlook folder to process
       Dim olPurgeFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
       Set olPurgeFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
       If olPurgeFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

       ' Iteration variables
       Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
       Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
       Dim sSavePathFS As String
       Dim sDelAtts As String

       For Each msg In olPurgeFolder.Items

         sDelAtts = ""

         ' We check each msg for attachments as opposed to using .Restrict("[Attachment] > 0")
         ' on our olPurgeFolder.Items collection.  The collection returned by the Restrict method
         ' will be dynamically updated each time we remove an attachment.  Each update will
         ' reindex the collection.  As a result, it does not provide a reliable means for iteration.
         ' This is why the For Each style loops will not work. ~~
         If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

           ' This While loop is controlled via the .Delete method which
           ' will decrement msg.Attachments.Count by one each time. ~~
           While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

             ' Save the attachment to the file system
             sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.path & "\" & msg.Attachments(1).filename
             msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS

             ' Build up a string to denote the file system save path(s)
             ' Format the string according to the msg.BodyFormat.
             If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                  sDelAtts = sDelAtts & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sSavePathFS & ">"
             Else
                  sDelAtts = sDelAtts & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & sSavePathFS & "'>" & sSavePathFS & "</a>"
             End If

             ' Delete the current attachment.  We use a "1" here instead of an "i"
             ' because the .Delete method will shrink the size of the msg.Attachments
             ' collection for us.  Use some well placed Debug.Print statements to see
             ' the behavior. ~~
             msg.Attachments(1).Delete

            Wend

           ' Modify the body of the msg to show the file system location of
           ' the deleted attachments.
           If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
              msg.Body = msg.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts
           Else
              msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & "<p></p><p>" & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts & "</p>"
           End If

            ' Save the edits to the msg.  If you forget this line, the attachments will not be deleted.  ~~
           msg.Save

          End If

        Next



  End Sub
  ```

Comment: you will want to use: For Each msg In olPurgeFolder.GetExplorer().Selection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the pickfolder code and select the items first.

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171941(v=office.11).aspx

**Untested code**

```
Sub SaveOLSelectedItemsAttachments()

Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
Dim x As Integer

Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection

' Ask the user to select a file system folder for saving the attachments
Dim oShell As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim fsSaveFolder As Object
Set fsSaveFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please Select a Save Folder:", 1)
If fsSaveFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
' Note:  BrowseForFolder doesn't add a trailing slash

For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count

    ' Iteration variables
    Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSavePathFS As String
    Dim sDelAtts As String

    Dim msg as mailitem
    Set msg = myOlSel.Item(x)

    sDelAtts = ""

    ' We check the item for attachments.
    ' The collection returned by the Restrict method
    ' will be dynamically updated each time we remove an attachment.  Each update will
    ' reindex the collection.  As a result, it does not provide a reliable means for iteration.
    ' This is why the For Each style loops will not work. ~~
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

        ' This While loop is controlled via the .Delete method which
        ' will decrement msg.Attachments.Count by one each time. ~~
        While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

            ' Save the attachment to the file system
            sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.path & "\" & msg.Attachments(1).filename
            msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS

            ' Build up a string to denote the file system save path(s)
            ' Format the string according to the msg.BodyFormat.
            If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                sDelAtts = sDelAtts & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sSavePathFS & ">"
            Else
                sDelAtts = sDelAtts & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & sSavePathFS & "'>" & sSavePathFS & "</a>"
            End If

            ' Delete the current attachment.  We use a "1" here instead of an "i"
            ' because the .Delete method will shrink the size of the msg.Attachments
            ' collection for us.  Use some well placed Debug.Print statements to see
            ' the behavior. ~~
            msg.Attachments(1).Delete

         Wend

         ' Modify the body of the msg to show the file system location of
         ' the deleted attachments.
         If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            msg.Body = msg.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts
         Else
            msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & "<p></p><p>" & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts & "</p>"
         End If

          ' Save the edits to the msg.  If you forget this line, the attachments will not be deleted.  ~~
         msg.Save

        End If

      Next

Next x

End Sub
```